# Cannot load module uninstall page - says module does not exist

Tags: 8, input-formats

I accidentally deleted the [Markdown filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/markdown) module from the file system while it was still enabled. So I installed it again, via the GUI.

Now I cannot load the module uninstall page - it says "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later", and the message in the log says `Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The "markdown" plugin does not exist. in Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->doGetDefinition()`

I have cleared caches, run cron, deleted `sites/default/files/php` ... all to no avail.

Any ideas?

Edit: I have just tried to enable the module again, and got this message: `Unable to install Markdown filter, markdown.settings already exists in active configuration.` I looked through the config and cache_config tables and cannot find this setting.

Comment: Try adding it manually in core.extension config, e.g. with drush or a single config export and import. Apparently the module was forcibly removed there without being uninstalled properly.

Comment: Thanks Berdir. Any way to do that without shell access? I only have sftp.

Comment: Single config export and import can be done in the UI but the core.extension file might be excluded from that, as it's pretty special. You can do a full config export, download that as an archive in the UI, the extract it, change the file, upload it into the configured config sync folder (usually sites/default/files/config_SOMEHASH/sync) and then go to config sync to import it.

Comment: I tried to do this using the import/export config GUI ( since it was not core.extension but markdown.settings that I needed to delete). However after exporting, extracting, deleting the file and then recompressing & importing, it said "Your file is uploaded and ready to import" but nothing showed on the sync tab. I fixed it in the DB, see my answer,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out there **was** a `markdown.settings` entry in the database (in the `config` or `cache_config` table, I forget which). I deleted this row and then it was possible to install and then uninstall the module.